# How to pipe multiple binary files to an application which reads from stdin

Tags: linux, shell, centos, pipe

For a single file,

```
$ my_app < file01.binary
```

For multiple files,

```
$ cat file*.binary | my_app
```

Each binary file is of size 500MB and the total size of all file*.binary is around 8GB. Based on my understanding, `cat` will first concatenate all files then redirect the single big file to `my_app`.

Is there a better way to send multiple binary files to `my_app` without first concatenating them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. `cat` will just read lines/blocks from the input files in a loop and print them to the pipe. No worries.

The "concatenate" in `cat` means that it concatenates its input to its output. It does not imply that it concatenates its input(s) in memory first.

Answer (score 1):

```
ls file*.binary | xargs cat | xargs my_app
```

xargs is a command to build and execute commands from standard input. It converts input from standard input into arguments to a command.